# How to send an mail from my domain using SMTP in Python?

Tags: python, email

I am trying to send mail from my domain using below script.

While hitting this line `smtplib.SMTP_SSL('mail.abc.com:587')` interpreter is hanged until terminate manually.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this..?

```
import smtplib

fromaddr = "user@abc.com"
toaddrs  = "user1@abc.com"

msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\n\r\n"
   % (fromaddr, toaddrs))

msg += str(stdout)

try :

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('mail.abc.com:587')

server.set_debuglevel(1)

server.starttls()

server.ehlo

server.login('user@abc.com','******')

server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)

server.quit()

except smtplib.SMTPException, e :

print e
```

Comment: Does mail.abc.com have port 587 open? Is there a SMTP server listening? Does you firewall allow access to mail.abc.com:587?

Comment: Yes phd, i was checked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `SMTP_SSL` — use `SMTP`. It's either `SMTP_SSL` or `SMTP + starttls()` but not both.

Default port for `SMTP_SSL` is 465.

Comment: After setting Security Mode as none in SMTP server it worked for me.